# Source exposure of Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Are the sources of files in 'pages/' exposed?

For example, if you configure a page for administrators in the pages/admin path and block access from Middleware, is it good for security?

Answer (score 0):

yes it's good for security reason

And you can block specific user by role to route in /admin page

you can easily do this thing by token store in cookie

And It is Absolutely good for security purpose

Because it is executing on Backend Side not in Client side

So, Client can't intercept on it